# Rolling Some Dice...Look But Don't Touch

Tags: c#, oop

Does anyone have any thoughts on passing full objects as variables as opposed to only pointers to the functions of the full object?

For example, I have a Dice object with two methods:

- RollDice(), randomizes the dice count
- GetCount(), retrieves the value

Now, I need to utilize the dice for more than just player moving, other objects need to be able to look at the Dice as well. Now, it seems wrong to me to pass the whole Dice object to these other objects, since then those objects would 'technically' be able to re-roll the Dice. Is it good or bad programming to pass only the GetCount function pointer to these other objects? Essentially saying "I'm not giving you the Dice, but I'll show you how to read them.".

Thoughts?

Comment: What programming language? Also, if you don't want to pass a function pointer to a `GetCount` function, why not just pass the value of the di(c)e as a number?

Comment: @Matt - I'm working on this in C#

Comment: I appreciate everyone's insight on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that its an excellent oportunity to use the OBSERVER PATTERN (GoF);

```
public class Dice
{
    private List<IDiceObserver> observers;
    public void RegisterObserver(IDiceObserver observer)
    {
        this.observers.Add(observer);
    }

    private Int32 count;
    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.count;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.count = value;
            foreach (IDiceObserver observer in this.observers)
                observer.DiceRolled(new DiceParameters(this.count));
        }
    }

    public void RollDice()
    {
        this.Count = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next();
    }

    public Dice()
    {
        this.observers = new List<IDiceObserver>();
    }
}
```

Do you need any further explanation on pattern, or other classes implementations????

Comment: Observer may not know the Dice class if you imagine them in a bigger context, for example, a Game class, wich has a Dice object, and a list of Players, I would implement the responsability for registering the Players as DiceObservers as a Game instance method called InitializeGame(), where I would loop through each player and call the method this way; myDice.RegisterObserver(player). Understand my point?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass them an integer?  This means they are decoupled from the dice.

If you are using dependency injection to inject the dice into service objects for each move, then create an interface that only contains the GetCount() method.

Comment: There is the one problem with this approach that I didn't make clear.  I could pass the dice value to the objects that need it, but it would require me to keep track of everything that needs the value and to make sure they are all updated on every roll.  I am looking to allow the objects to 'query' the dice only on occasion as needed.

Comment: The objects interested in the dice value should then take as a constructor argument interface IDiceCount.  This has one method on it for GetCount().

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class for dice to make them immutable. The wrapper can be implemented either by delegation or by subclassing and overriding RollDice(). Then pass a wrapper object instead of a mutable Dice object when you want to guarantee that it won't change.

Comment: Do you mean extending Dice with an immutable implementation that stubs out RollDice? In my opinion this break the Liskov Substitution Principle because RollDice no longer has the behaviour expected by the calling class.

Comment: @Martin - You make a valid point. I think the delegation architecture is much cleaner for something like this.

Comment: @Martin - after more reflection, I think that with a slight change the subtype proposal works cleanly: make the (mutable) Dice class the subclass of the immutable one. I don't think that breaks LSP provided the superclass does not specify that it is immutable but merely provides no means to roll the dice.

Comment: That definitely solves that particular problem :) "Require no more, promise no less". I personally prefer my solution below, because I think it more closely models the real world, but yours is a fine solution.

Comment: @Martin - I agree. Your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Dice object should have a DiceValue or FaceValue attribute. You could pass this value instead of passing the dice themselves. This controls access to dice behaviour, and also avoids the [primitive obsession](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/PrimitiveObsession.html) code smell which would result from passing just the integer value of the face. It also keeps your dice value more abstract, so you could later use values other than numbers, such as special face values, etc.